# How to reveal multiple html?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, web

Suppose that, i got this pseudocode:

```
itemset1[apple,orange]
itemset2[banana,potato]

<div>
  <header>
    <h3>Mylist</h3>
   </header>
   <ul>
    <li>itemset1[]</li>
  </ul>
</div>


<div>
  <header>
    <h3>Mylist</h3>
   </header>
   <ul>
    <li>itemset2[]</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Is there any way that letting me write only once the html code? like

```
<div>
  <header>
    <h3>Mylist</h3>
   </header>
   <ul>
    <li>items</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

and reveals twice like the first example(one for itemset1 and one for itemset2) i can use evrything javascript or php but prefer javascript

Comment: use angular JS.

Comment: Practically any coding language under the sun will allow you to merge arrays...

Comment: Use php for it. Create an array of object with item and then use for loop for it.

Comment: By using both Javascript & PHP it can be done. But, it's better to use Javascript for any kind of DOM manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

There're two ways (or more?). Rendering with `PHP` or `JavaScript`.

#### With PHP at view

For example, using `foreach ($itemset1 as $item)` probably what you want.

```
<div>
    <header>
        <h3>Mylist</h3>
    </header>
    <ul>
    <?php foreach ( $itemset1 as $item ) { ?>
        <li><?php echo $item ?></li>
    <?php } ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

#### With JavaScript

In this case, I'm using `AngularJS` for rendering data. Assuming you have known what `AngularJS` is and have been prepared for that.

```
<div>
    <header>
        <h3>Mylist</h3>
    </header>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in itemset1">{{ item }}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Of course, If you like, jQuery is also a good choice for you. But hate the jQuery `append` expression. And it's inconvenient.

See that reference:

[PHP: foreach - Manaual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

[AngularJS: API: ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

Comment: look what i answer!!

Answer (score 0):

Sure but now i have to write

```
<div>
    <header>
        <h3>Mylist</h3>
    </header>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in itemset1">{{ item }}</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div>
    <header>
        <h3>Mylist</h3>
    </header>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in itemset2">{{ item }}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Any way that i can avoid writing twice all of this div,header,ul,li elements?